# My template function with the universal reference does not work

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to make a template function that is flexible and can take both rvalue and lvalue. This is how I wrote it:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) normalize_pose(T&& pose)
{
    if (pose > 2 * M_PI) return std::forward<T>(pose - 2* M_PI);
}
```

So I double checked the function and it seems correct to me. Then I have decided to test it and wrote:

```
int a = 2;
auto test = factorgraph::normalize_pose(a);
```

I get this error:

```
 error: use of ‘decltype(auto) factorgraph::normalize_pose(T&&) [with T = int&]’ before deduction of ‘auto’
```

If I try to add `<int>`, I get an error that no such function exist.

Comment: What about the `else` branch?, What would the function returns `if(not)`?

Comment: Your example is strange btw, as forwarding is not needed, const ref does the job here.

Comment: @Jarod42 You mean because of the template type deduction rule?

Comment: You don't say what version of c++ you are compiling against. Use of clever deduced return types needs better than C++11

Comment: @UsingCpp That is the answer!!!! It could not deduce the type with my example, omg, how stupid I am...

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes, added the tag now

Comment: I can't reproduce this error message.

Comment: @Brian Try with ```int a = 2```, the code will be out of if statement and auto won't be able to deduce the type, I should have added which int I used

Comment: Still can't reproduce it. The arguments passed at run-time should not cause a compile-time error. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b09f50dbccdb549f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```
if (pose > 2 * M_PI) return std::forward<T>(pose) - 2* M_PI;
```

Apply `std::forward` to variable only.

And you also need to return value for the else branch (of the same type to satisfy 
 `decltype(auto)`).

But in your case, a simple:

```
template<typename T>
auto normalize_pose(const T& pose)
{
    return (pose > 2 * M_PI) ? pose - 2 * M_PI : pose;
}
```

handles all cases.

Comment: Yes correct but I still get this error:
```error: use of ‘decltype(auto) factorgraph::normalize_pose(T&&) [with T = int&]’ before deduction of ‘auto’
  auto test = factorgraph::normalize_pose(a);```

Comment: Pretty sure `decltype(auto)` is also not needed since `std::forward<T>(pose) - 2* M_PI` is most likely a prvalue expression and the else branch wouldn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver Dunno guys, I am here to learn if needed. I just followed the example from the book "Effective Modern C++"

Comment: Unrelated: `decltype(auto)` simply can be `T`. I don't know why OP want this way!

Comment: Updated code fails if an integer is passed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13731e038276b632

Comment: Although that may be moot as normalizing an `int` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @UsingCpp According to the book I have mentioned it should be decltype because auto slices off the & part due to the template type deduction rule

Comment: @NathanOliver because it is not always int, what if I have supplied float?

Comment: It still wont work because of `decltype(auto)`.  Do you really want a reference returned?

Comment: @NathanOliver No but in some cases returning the reference will be important.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think my knowledge stops there. Can you explain what exactly might go wrong with this code?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Fixed. Didn't want to change OP's code that much. (we can probably get rid of template too, and just use `double`).

Comment: @Jarod42 But what happens if I supply &int? I guess T return value will be int?

Comment: @Edmund The code as it is now is really what you would want.  Using `decltyp(auto)`, to get a reference returned can't work because `pose - 2 * M_PI` will not have the same type as `pose`.  For `decltype(auto)` to work all control paths need to return the same type and you just can't do that in this situation.

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean if pose is int, the return type will be double/float?

Comment: @Edmund No.  Lets say `T` is a double.  then `pose - 2 * M_PI` would be of type `double`.  `pose` on the other hand would be of type `double const &` since that is the type of `pose`.  `double` and `double const &` are not the same type so `decltype(auto)` fails.  You can use Jarod's solution and then if you need a normalized value, but also setting the variable to that normalized value, you can use something like `auto foo = (bar = normalize(bar)) * more_stuff;`

Comment: @NathanOliver Just a quick question, so why does the author of Effective Modern C++ writes this as a good example?
```template<typename Container, typename Index>
decltype(auto)
authAndAccess(Container&& c, Index i)
{
authenticateUser();
return std::forward<Container>(c)[i];
}```

Comment: @Edmund Because that function can only return a single type.  That means they can return the exact reference type.  Had the function been `template<typename Container, typename Index> decltype(auto) authAndAccess(Container&& c, Index i) { if (authenticateUser()) return std::forward<Container>(c)[i]; else return foo; }` then you are returning 2 different types and it can't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay but if the else return type was double (for example multiplied by M_PI) then my example code will be valid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193779/discussion-between-nathanoliver-and-edmund).